# How do I get gocmq interrupt signal on golang?

Tags: go

**  I use goczmq, but I don't catch system interrupt when run server on Windwos. Why?**

```
signal_channel := make(chan os.Signal)
signal.Notify(signal_channel)
go goczmq....
<-signal_channel
```

Answer (score 1):

I did a quick example and seems to work as expected. 
Having code in `a.go` :

```
package main

import (
"os"
"os/signal"
"time"
"fmt"
)

func main() {

fmt.Println( "Started...")
signal_channel := make(chan os.Signal)
signal.Notify(signal_channel)
go func() {
    // do whatever...
    time.Sleep(10 *time.Second)
}()
sig1 := <-signal_channel
fmt.Println( "\n\nGot signal: ", sig1 )

fmt.Println( "Done.")

}
```

and

```
> go run a.go &
[1] 26515
Started...

>kill -HUP %1

Got signal:  hangup
Done. 

> go run a.go &
[1] 26768
> Started...

kill -USR1 %1

Got signal:  user defined signal 1
```

Also:

```
go run a.go  // + Press CTRL-Z
Started...
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 go run a.go

Got signal:  stopped
Done.
```

and

```
> go run a.go // + Press CTRL-C 
Started...
^C

Got signal:  interrupt
Done.
```

If in your case it is not visible maybe it is consumed in gorutine. 
Like in:

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "time"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    fmt.Println( "Started...")
    signal_channel := make(chan os.Signal)
    signal.Notify(signal_channel)
    go func() {
        // do whatever...
        sig2 := <-signal_channel
        fmt.Println( "gorutine sig2: ", sig2)
        time.Sleep(10 *time.Second)
    }()

    time.Sleep(10 *time.Second)
    sig1 := <-signal_channel
    fmt.Println( "\n\nGot signal: ", sig1 )

    fmt.Println( "Done.")

}
```

which gets:

> go run a.go 
>       Started...

```
^Cgorutine sig2:  interrupt
```

Comment: thanks,reply. But I add goczmq to the example,It is not working on Windwos